# How to compile Java programs from Eclipse using terminal on a Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, compiler-construction, terminal

I am trying to learn how to compile Java programs made on Eclipse, an IDE, in Terminal. Starting out right after opening terminal, what are the steps I should take to compile a program I've made on Eclipse in terminal? Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:** I got as far as navigating to my java folder, and to the package that houses my programs, and did the line javac Hello.java (Hello is the basic "Hello World" program I'm trying to compile) but when I do java Hello I get a large error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello (wrong name: homeWorkPackage/Hello)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: There's no straight forward way of doing this since eclipse projects tend to have complex classpaths. You are best off using maven.

Comment: Please refer the [official tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html) (assuming you have the JDK properly configured:

- Change the directory to the directory where your file is saved (using the `cd` command)
- Use  the command `javac [filename.java]` to compile the program
- there should be a class file in the directory now

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, compiling from the terminal is not needed, however you can do it like this:

Navigate to the project directory containing the `.java` files. You can then run `javac ClassName.java` e.g. `javac Cake.java` [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) is the Java language compiler. This command will compile the source (your `.java` file). To run it you can go `java ClassName`. e.g. `java Cake`. `java` starts the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). The named class will be loaded and execution started. You don't include the `.class` file extension one the `java ClassName` command.

When you need you navigate around the file system I think [this](http://ss64.com/osx/) page gives a good overview of the commands but here are a few that you might need for this task:

`cd` - change directory (followed by directory name) e.g. `cd Documents`

`ls` - list information about files (can take some parameters)

`..` can take you back a directory. e.g. `cd ..` will bump you back one directory

you can also hit `tab` to auto complete a directory/file name.

Comment: Thanks for the help to get there! Everything goes fine up until I do java Classname. I tried it for my basic java program titled Hello which is just Hello World, but it gave me this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello (wrong name: homeWorkPackage/Hello) followed by a long string of statements starting with "at java.something" Any way to fix?

Comment: Hmmm... java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError will be thrown when the JVM is not able to find a particular class at runtime that was available during compile time. You may want to look for differences in your build time and run time class paths. If you search the error that you received you will find some more info on this site. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java/5756989#5756989) is a question dealing with this error. And [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) is the java documentation about it.

Comment: On another note, is there a particular reason you need to compile from the terminal? I only ask because it seems like you are in the process of learning and it might not be worth it to over complicate this with unneeded steps (unless there is a particular reason for compiling & running this way). I hope that I have been of some assistance in this matter. Cheers